# Exhaustion by compact sets in $\mathbb{C}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, complex-analysis

> Let $U\subseteq\mathbb{C}^n$ be open. For every $j\in\mathbb{N}$ define $$K_j:=\{z\in U:\left\|{z}\right\|_{\infty}\le j,d_{\infty}(z,\mathbb{C}^n\setminus U)\ge 1/j\}.$$
>
> Then the following holds:
>
> 1. Every $K_j$ is compact.
> 2. For all $j$ we have $K_j\subseteq int (K_{j+1})$.
> 3. $U$ is the union of the $K_j$.
> 4. For every compact $K\subseteq U$ there exists $j$ such that $K\subseteq K_j$.

The only thing I don't understard is the proof of 2.

> 2. The set $$C=\{z\in U:\left\|{z}\right\|_{2}< j+1,d_{2}(z,\mathbb{C}^n\setminus U)> 1/(j+1)\}$$is open, contains $K_j$ and is contained in $K_{j+1}$. Hence $K_j\subseteq int(K_{j+1})$.

I don't see why $K_j\subseteq C\subseteq K_{j+1}$. My questions are:

a) About $K_j\subseteq C$, why $d_{\infty}(z,\mathbb{C}^n\setminus U)\ge 1/j$ would imply that $d_{2}(z,\mathbb{C}^n\setminus U)\ge 1/(j+1)$?

b) About $C\subseteq K_{j+1}$, why $\left\|{z}\right\|_{2}< j+1$ implies that $\left\|{z}\right\|_{\infty}\le j+1$?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be $d_∞$ in the proof. All the norms are equivalent and all the properties being proved are topological, so it really holds for balls of any norm. But the proof should use the same norm as the statement.

Regarding your points a), b), they actually hold since $d_∞ ≤ d_2$ and $\lVert·\rVert_∞ ≤ \lVert·\rVert_2$. But there is a problem with the other two implications.

Comment: Oh, I see it. It was just that. Thank you very much.